# How do I find the distance travelled in time $t$ in following question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

The particle starts from the origin with an initial velocity $u$ and the acceleration of the particle is increasing linearly with time $t$ as $bt$. Now what will the distance traveled by particle in the time $t$ be?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2):

Homework type question.
Quick answer is - As the acceleration increases linearly, you can consider a uniform acceleration of $a = \frac{bt}{2}$, and then use $s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$

Answer (score 2):

Acceleration is the second derivative of position, so if the acceleration is equal to $bt$ then:

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = bt $$

You simply need to solve this differential equation and use the initial conditions you're provided. In this case you can use a technique called [ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) (which basically means guessing). Suppose you have some equation:

$$ x = At^3 + Bt^2 + Ct + D $$

then:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 3At^2 + 2Bt + C $$

and:

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = 6At + 2B $$

Could you find values for $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ that would make this solve your problem?